Short-circuiting an electrolytic cell with metal dendrites and observing interesting chaotic 1/f noise
While conducting home experiments on the electrolytic deposition of copper in a micro-gap (2-3 mm), under a microscope (x40) I observed interesting effects of short-circuiting by metal dendrites of the anode and cathode - similarly, which leads to fires in lithium-ion batteries where Li dendrites deposited.
Electrolyte: CH3COOH (9%), can be with CuSO4 (~0.1M) or without copper salt. If a copper anode is used, copper dendrites will grow due to copper dissolution at the anode and reduction at the cathode.
(You can see video of quiet copper dendrites growth from this link:
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wRkEf1wb_iT9HQ
)
At low current (1-2 mA) - after the formation of a short circuit (and drop average voltage to 0.45-0.50 V), a strong noise is observed in the loudspeaker of an audio amplifier connected in parallel to the electrochemical cell. In the visual absence of any processes, even the release of gases microbubbles. Could quantum effects be involved if electrodeposition results to a nanometer-sized gaps? Something like Quantum Point Contacts.
The noise oscillograms video [low-current, no sparks, no gas evolution, visually full dendrite short-circuit of my electrochemical cell]
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wQps4Jer0TRdTg
The noise are ~1/f character, if do FFT conversion on digital o-scope.
Perhaps as yet another hypothesis - may be micro- and nanowires are formed there and immediately burn out even from such a low current?

Isn't 1/f noise expected when you measure something that is essentially an integral of an uncorrelated white noise?

Your experiment is reminiscent of an demo of fractal formation between two electrodes with zinc and tin solutions. Distance does not appear in this case. The dendrites patterns will form regardless even if the distance is considerable even on wet wood. For example see this beautiful video that shows that high voltage also forms the dendrite like burning pattern on moist wood with salt solution. Patterns on wood with electricity However, the source noise should not be mysterious. You have a ran

1/f noise is "flicker noise", and even shows up in carbon resistors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_noise

But possibly there formation also Quantum point contacts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_point_contact), if current will not reach surge threshold?
(Probably in automatic mode I need to take thousands of resistance measurements at different voltages and build a histogram of how they are distributed in order to find quantization if there is any. And for some nanoampere currents, not for 1 mA!).

For high currents, everything is of course clear) If I take a source of 200 volts with a power of 20 watts and pass electricity through a short-circuited cell, then under a microscope I can see very nice chaotic electric arcs. As like the legendary Phoenix burns and resurrect again (surge - electrodeposition - surge oscillatory cycle): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAu3ldoPcD0

Hmm... I find nice article from 2001 year where authors got the Quantum contact by simplest electrodeposition: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/nl010043t (full text can be seen in sci-hub portal...) and yet another from 2018 year where got silver dendrites short-circuit with quantum conductance properties: https://www.reed.edu/physics/332/pdf/Quantized%20Conductance%20-%20Dendrites.pdf

But it is certainly necessary to be able to distinguish quantum effects from simple formation microwires/Joule heating surge microwires effects and infinite chaotic cycle...

Interesting, with tin dendrites, individual noise components on an digital oscilloscope screen reach a minimum duration of 2-5 microseconds, while with copper the shortest chaotic noise components (distinguishable from average noise) are on the order of 5-10 milliseconds.

It will hard to suggest or verify a quantum effect based on home experiments. Can you contact local physicists? Post more details in a physics rather than chemistry.

Yes, I can ask people at the university where I studied many years ago.
